# node has term - show all parents of this term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

A node has a taxonomy term. My aim is to show  a view on node page, that displays all parents of this taxonomy term and the term as well. Is it possible to acomplish in views? I use views 3 and drupal 7. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although you're looking for a Views solution, if you were to do it custom, e.g with [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) you could use [taxonomy_get_parents](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/7)

Just mentioning in case others looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Hierarchical Term Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter) also [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) has some formatters for it.

Comment: unfortunately none of it works with views

Comment: You can create view mode with those formatters only and in views - render a node as a field. Not the most elegant way, but should work if you don't find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but my approach requires some PHP knowledge. First, you need to install [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. Then in view defintion you need to add "Global:PHP" field and in that field you enter in Output code text something like:

```
<?php
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($data->field_having_term[0]['raw']['tid']);
// now $parents contains array of all parents' objects
// you can check that with dpm($parents); if you have devel module enabled

// if you'd like to print all parents' names, you can for instance
$parents_names = array();
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    $parents_names[] = $parent->name;
}

print implode(", ", $parents_names);

?>
```

A few remarks:
$data is your content and field_having_term is machine name of field referencing the therm. I guess there are better ways of solving this, but this one is currently working of me in Drupal 7. If someone has a better approach, comment please.